# WP query taxonomy input differs to output?

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy

I'm trying to build a custom query and I need to include the current category ID. I previously had the WP_Query args as:

```
Array
(
    [post_status] => publish
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [post_type] => courses
    [cat] => 70
```

When I output SQL result behind this argument query using $query->request; the taxonomies read as 95 and 203, instead of 70?

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts 
            INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) 
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id) WHERE 1=1 
            AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (95,203)
```

Can anyone tell me how/why this is happening and what I need to do to find 95,203 from this initial 70 so that I can also build this query manually?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you please post your entire code for the query. Are you using `the_query($args);` or `$query = new WP_Query($args)`? Yon mention `$query->request` in your question, so I'll assume the latter. If that is the case, you may have filters/actions in play that are affecting the query.

Comment: This is expected, if you go through the long journey from  `WP_Query()` to  `WP_Tax_Query() ` ;-) I will post you the "why" later today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A curious journey of a "`cat`"

Let's assume we have the following category hierarchy:

[image]

where the relevant rows from the `wp_term_taxonomy` table are:

[image: wp_term_taxonomy]

We want to query all posts in the *animals* `category` where the `id` is `65`:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 65 ) );
```

and try to understand why the resulting SQL is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
    FROM wp_posts  
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
        ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
    WHERE 1=1  
    AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (15,70, 75) ) 
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
    AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date 
    DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

i.e. the part why `65` is changed into `15, 70, 75`.

**Let's start:**

In `WP_Query()` our query is transformed into:

```
$tax_query[0] = array( 'taxonomy'           => 'category',
                       'terms'              =>  array( 65 ),
                       'field'              => 'term_id',
                       'include_children'   => 1
                   );
```

before it's feed to the hungry:

```
 WP_Tax_Query( $tax_query )
```

which generates the SQL query from the `$tax_query` array.

There it's merged with the defaults:

```
array( 'taxonomy'          => '',
       'terms'             => array(),
       'include_children'  => true,
       'field'             => 'term_id',
       'operator'          => 'IN',
);
```

When the `WP_Query()` object wants the resulting SQL query back it calls the `WP_TAX_Query::get_sql()` method.

Then our array is "*cleaned*" and "*transformed*":

**a)** It's **cleaned** via the `WP_TAX_Query::clean_query()` method, resulting in:

```
array( 'taxonomy'           => 'category',
       'terms'              =>  array( 61, 13, 65 ),
       'field'              => 'term_id',
       'include_children'   =>  1,
       'operator'           => 'IN',
);
```

where the child categories have been included with `get_term_children()`.

**b)** It's **transformed** via the `WP_TAX_Query::transform_query()` method, where the `term_id` is transformed into the corresponding `term_taxonomy_id` values.

In our case it's the result of:

```
 SELECT term_taxonomy_id
 FROM wp_term_taxonomy
 WHERE taxonomy = 'category'
 AND term_id IN (15, 61, 65)
```

namely `15, 70` and `75`:

[image]

Then our tax query looks like this:

```
array( 'taxonomy'           => 'category',
       'terms'              =>  array( 15, 70, 75 ),
       'field'              => 'term_taxonomy_id',
       'include_children'   =>  1,
       'operator'           => 'IN',
);
```

before it's added to the SQL query parts of `WP_Query()`:

```
"join": INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
            ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)

"where": AND ( tfl_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (15,70,75) )
```

The end ;-)

---

### Extra:

One can also play directly with the `WP_TAX_Query` class, to investigate the generated SQL.

For example:

```
    $tax_query = array();
    $tax_query[0] = array(
                   'taxonomy'           => 'category',
                   'terms'              =>  array( 65 ),
                   'field'              => 'term_id',
                   'include_children'   => 1
               );
    $t = new WP_TAX_Query( $tax_query );
    print_r( $t->get_sql( $GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts, 'ID' ) );
```

will give the following output:

```
Array
(
    [join] =>  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (tfl_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    [where] =>  AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (15,70,75) )
)
```

Comment: Best answer ever? Thanks birgire that's the answer I was after x100

Comment: Can I invoke WP_Tax_Query manually then and get the snippet of SQL to append to my larger query?

Comment: Yes, you can call it manually to generate the where+join SQL parts. Check out this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/X59i4j2G).

Comment: ps: I added it to the answer, in case the pastebin link goes down ;-)